# gmaps4rails get latitude and longitude in the server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gmaps4rails

I'm reading about `'gmaps4rails'`, but I have a question about the gem. Is possible obtain the location (lat, lng) only with the address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is, but I would first use the `Geocoder` gem.

```
gem 'geocoder'
```

You need to create a migration to add latitude and longitude floats to your table

```
rails g migration AddLatitudeAndLongitueToModel latitude:float longitude:float
```

Obviously, replace `Model` with your table name. then run `rake db:migrate`

Then in your model, make sure the attribute for an address is being geocoded

```
geocoded_by :location # replace location with the attribute of the address
```

I would also add this:

```
after_validation :geocode, if: ->(model_name){ model_name.location.present? and model_name.location_changed? }
```

to avoid unnecessary API requests. Once again, change `model_name` with your model and `location` with the attribute that has the address.

When you you create a new post now, it will have longitude and latitude coordinates that you can use with `Gmap4rails`

So you can now you `Gmap4rails` like this:

```
hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@post) do |post, marker|
  marker.lat post.latitude
  marker.lng post.longitude
end
```

Here is the [GitHub docs](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) for the Geocoder gem. Has pretty much everything you need to know to add this to your app.

Hope this can get you started in the right direction.

Comment: I found this function: 
Geocoder.search("1 Twins Way, Minneapolis")
Geocoder.search("44.981667,-93.27833")
Geocoder.search("204.57.220.1")

Comment: @MrMins Thats what you really wanted... :D

Answer (score 2):

Yes this can be done by `geocoder.search` method.
I did this for getting the latitude the user's location/address .

```
  :lat => Geocoder.search(tweet.user.location.to_s).first.coordinates,
  :lng => Geocoder.search(tweet.user.location.to_s).first.coordinates
```

There is a nice railscasts here http://railscasts.com/episodes/273-geocoder

Comment: yes please have a look at the rails cast and gmaps4rails github page. There is everything you need just read the stuff.