# gmaps4rails in show view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I'd like to place a gmaps4rails map in a show view, but i have a problem with building a marker with current spots location. I couldn't find anything on the topic. Is it possible to do? (sorry for being a complete beginner)

That's what i tried so far.

```
def show
 @comments = @spot.comments
 @photos = @spot.photos

@hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@spot) do |spot, marker|
   marker.lat spot.latitude
   marker.lng spot.longitude
   marker.infowindow spot.name
end
```

EDIT:

view:

```
<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.13&amp;sensor=false&amp;libraries=geometry"          type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.14/src/markerclusterer_packed.js' type='text/javascript'></script>


 <div class="container">
  <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
 <div class="row galleria">
 <%= render_gallery_for @photos %>
  </div>


<div style='width: 800px;'>
    <div id="map" style='width: 800px; height: 400px;'></div>
  </div>   

  <script type="text/javascript">
  handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
  handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
    var marker = handler.addMarker(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
   handler.map.centerOn(marker);
  }); 
</script>

...
```

Comment: Few questions...Does your object, `@spot`, have a `latitude` and `longitude`? I wrote an answer on this that may benefit you here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/24590199/2456549

Comment: @JustinLicata Yes, it does. It all works when used on index view with "spots" instead of "spot".

Comment: ok, are you currently getting an error? (also check javascript console). make sure `@spot` is defined, make sure your `show.html.erb` has the appropriate `javascript` for GMap4Rails (`markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);`)

Comment: could you explain what do you mean by defining [@spot]

Comment: `@spot = Spot.find(params[:id])`. Perhaps you could paste more code from your `view`, `controller` or `errors` that you are getting that will help guide us to the answer quicker than just *assuming* what the error might be.

Comment: Spot is defined, and i don't get any errors - the marker just doesn't show. I edited the post and added part of my view. I hope that helps

Comment: could you show the generated html?

Comment: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:3300/assets/underscore-min.map` - that's an error i get right now.

Comment: ` <script type="text/javascript">
  handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
  handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
    var marker = handler.addMarker([{"lat":50.05105700000001,"lng":19.941979,"infowindow":"asdfaf"}]);
    handler.map.centerOn(marker);
  }); 
</script>` - and that's the javascript generated

Comment: A new error i got
`TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.setMap(a)')
MarkerClustererundefined:0
Clustererclusterer.js:12
buildbuilder.js:9
_createClustererhandler.js:149
(anonimowa funkcja)handler.js:20
apply
(anonimowa funkcja){main,geometry}.js:18:362
apply
trigger{main,geometry}.js:17:207
(anonimowa funkcja)
apply
trigger{main,geometry}.js:17:207
lf{main,geometry}.js:22:157
set{main,geometry}.js:21:727
d
apply
(anonimowa funkcja){main,geometry}.js:11:655`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to replace `addMarker` with `addMarkers` because the arg you are passing is an array.

You can use `addMarker` if you pass an object.

---

But if you use `addMarkers` change your code to:

```
 var markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
 handler.map.centerOn(markers[0]);
```

[See plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/YEbiXhRSZHn2i8Jlel41?p=preview)

Comment: well, still no markers show up and i get the same error as before

Comment: provide your html again please

Comment: i guess that's the interesting part
`<script type="text/javascript">
  handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
  handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
    var marker = handler.addMarkers([{"lat":50.05105700000001,"lng":19.941979}]);
    handler.map.centerOn(marker);
  }); 
</script> `